# Why is the new ES6 find method not recognised in JSBin?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, shim, jsbin

I have the following code which I believe to be correct and transpiler ES6/Babel option on but I get the following error.

```
"error"
"TypeError: nums.find is not a function
    at qezoze.js:11:18
    at qezoze.js:16:3
    at https://static.jsbin.com/js/prod/runner-3.34.2.min.js:1:13603
    at https://static.jsbin.com/js/prod/runner-3.34.2.min.js:1:10524"
```

This is my code at JS bin (https://jsbin.com/qezoze/edit?js,console)

```
/*jshint esnext: true */ 

(function() {

  'use strict';

  let nums = [1,2,3,4,5];

  let one = nums.find(num => num === 1);


  console.log(one);

}());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSBin is transpiling the code, but not loading the shims necessary for full support. We can see this if we inspect the document that's being run:

[image]

Note that there are no `script` elements except the one with your code. While one could add to `Array.prototype` from outside the window, given that nothing is set up to delay your code to give JSBin a chance to do that (and given that `Array.prototype.find` is apparently actually missing), apparently they're just not including the shims.

[It works](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&playground=false&code=%20%20'use%20strict'%3B%0A%0A%20%20let%20nums%20%3D%20%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%5D%3B%0A%0A%20%20let%20one%20%3D%20nums.find(num%20%3D%3E%20num%20%3D%3D%3D%201)%3B%0A%0A%0A%20%20console.log(one)%3B%0A) on Babel's REPL.